# How can I use a Python List in a SQL Where IN Clause?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, where-clause

I have a CSV file with a few columns and 800 records, and one of those columns is a variable that I need to filter in a SQL Query.

_

I thought about reading that CSV as a Dataframe, ->

then get a list from that DF, ->

and then use the list in the `WHERE X IN (List[0]','List[1]','[List[2']....)`

_

How can I do it with Python?

Thanks

Comment: Use Pandasql: https://pypi.org/project/pandasql/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @wilian, but I meant how could I do this using python because I didnt know, besides which library to use

I figure it out a way to do it:

Imported my csv file into a dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv(path)
```

Then I made a list of the column I needed

```
list = df['list'].tolist()
```

Then I turned that list into a single string

```
list1 = """' , '""".join([str(item) for item in list])
list2 = "'" + list1[:] + "'" + list1[0:0]
```

Needed to do that way because the SQL Where X IN ('') clause needs to be written with ' and commas

Then I got a single string like this

```
list2 = 'a','b','c'
```

Then I used read_sql from pandas using a f'string

```
query = f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE X IN ({list2})"

result = pd.read_sql(query,conn)
```